# What is the IntelliJ IDEA shortcut declare a final variable if I use shortcut to introduce variable?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I use the keyboard shortcut 'Extract Variable' 
<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in Mac OS.

IDE shows popup window 'Declare final' with a checkbox.

How to set checkbox without a mouse?

I know about settings <kbd>Code Style</kbd> | <kbd>Java</kbd> | <kbd>Code Generation</kbd> | <kbd>Make generated local variables final</kbd>, but it's not what I need. I don't want to set a checkbox manually every time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a little underline underneath the 'f':

[image]

If you invoke your modifier - on a PC I use ALT - you will be able to toggle the finality of your variable.

Comment: Thanks! ALT + F. It's ok!